# Web.config mapping path to static file

Tags: iis, web-config

I'm using IIS for serving static files only.  I would like to map the path /foo to bar.html (or any other file).  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you are using IIS 6, there is [**URL Rewriter**](http://urlrewriter.net/).
- For IIS 7 and above, there is the [official **IIS URL Rewrite** 2.0 module](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) from Microsoft.

There are also many other URL rewrite modules for IIS, the above ones are free and I've successfully used both of them in my projects.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at doing some URL Rewriting check this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx

If your mapping needs are simple I would roll my own HttpHandler:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228090.aspx

But since you are serving static files and don't want any custom code, you can try to use outbound rules:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/657/creating-outbound-rules-for-url-rewrite-module/

Comment: Edited my answer, you should try outbound rules. Not easy to set it up though